# Multiple languages in a single JetBrains IDE?

Tags: jetbrains-ide

Novice question, perhaps, but — I've typically associated my projects with different IDEs based on language and on historical accident, but I have a project that has multiple languages (notably JavaScript and Python) and would prefer to have full language support for all of them in one place.

Can I just open up my WebStorm project, for example, in IntelliJ and have it work there, without disrupting any of the settings associated with the project (so I can go back to WebStorm if there is an issue)? If so, how do I simultaneously work with JavaScript (which needs to know about the yarn setup) and Python (which needs to know about a venv)?

Comment: 1) Python and JavaScript? Use PyCharm Pro -- https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/#chooseYourEdition

Comment: 2) All JetBrains IDEs store their project settings in `.idea` subfolder. If you open WebStorm project in IntelliJ IDEA then it will overwrite settings when closing the project. 3) #2 can be work-arounded (by meaning of having 2 different "projects" -- storing project settings in different locations for each IDE), but it's a hassle (as you need to configure each separately). See https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-170102 if interested

Comment: @LazyOne: Just to be sure: Some specifics: 1. What will happen the the WebStorm settings I now have for the project? Will they be preserved so that if I go back to WebStorm things will be the same? 2. Will IntelliJ use the settings I have for the project now in WebStorm? 3. If I back up the .idea folder before trying IntelliJ can I restore it and be right back where I was in WebStorm (in case IntelliJ doesn't work out for me)?

Comment: WebStorm (as well as PhpStorm) has quite simple project setup (only 1 module of WEB type). Other IDEs (IntelliJ specifically) can normally have more than one module in a project (e.g. each microservice as a separate module; or back-end in one module; front-end in another, admin panel in another etc). If you open WS project in IntelliJ, the IDE should read the settings just fine (not expecting issues here). But it MAY save **some** settings that WebStorm then will not be able to read properly (in the past/quite few years ago it sometimes was changing the module type that WS does not understand)

Comment: If you plan to go back to WebStorm later then just backup (ZIP) `.idea` while the project is closed in the IDE (as it saves the settings on project close/IDE exit) and restore when needed again.

Comment: @LazyOne How do I get the External Tools I've set up in WS into IJ? Settings other than that seem to sync (I have settings sync enabled for all IDEs) but External Tools don't seem to be part of that.

Comment: Hmm. Must be https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-309872. Anyway: Copy appropriate config file manually from one IDE to another: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/directories-used-by-the-ide-to-store-settings-caches-plugins-and-logs.html#config-directory (while the target IDE is closed, of course)